# Grouping dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, grouping

Below is my function to create and remove text boxes dynamically, however I am looking for a method by which I can group these items into one text box (preferably through the use of a button located below the text boxes or something..). The jist is that I've four columns, each with these functions to add and remove the text boxes, therefore I also wondered if that after grouping the text boxes would the undo function now be useless? Apologies for my lack of knowledge in this area, and thank you in advance for your help

```js
function addText(e) {
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    area = week ? week.querySelector('textarea') : null,
    text = area ? area.value : '';
  if (text.length) {
    let item = document.createElement('p');
    item.innerText = text;
    week.appendChild(item);
    area.value = '';
  }
}

function removeText(e) {
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    item = week ? week.querySelector('p:last-of-type') : null;
  if (item)
    item.remove()
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.closest('[add-text]'))
    addText(event);
  if (event.target.closest('[remove-text]'))
    removeText(event);
})
```

```html
<div id="planner">
  <div class="week week1">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Weeks</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="button" add-text>Add text</button>
      <button type="button" remove-text>Undo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week week2">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="button" add-text>Add text</button>
      <button type="button" remove-text>Undo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post your HTML to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by grouping text boxes into one text box? Do you mean having one text box and adding/removing rows from it? You can't have a text box in a text box, as far as I know.

Comment: @ggorlen so I'll click a button on my page, creating new text boxes, and then would like to have another button to form both of these boxes into one i.e. take the text from both text boxes and put them into one in the same location.

Comment: By "text box", you mean a paragraph element or input element? I'm still unclear as to your desired result.

Comment: The product of the "addText" function is what I mean, sorry for the confusion